# Can an executable be run as a part of a blob-triggered Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, ffmpeg, azure-functions, nreco

I know executables are suitable for timer triggers, but since the timer trigger doesn't require parallel access to the executable, I wasn't sure if it works for blob triggers. Let's say I have 10 messages in my queue, will the Azure runtime cause a lock on the executable? Or will it manage just fine with 10 parallel instances? The context to this question is a wrapper library (NReco) I'm using around the FFMPeg utility. The binaries for FFMPeg are required during the exeution of my Azure function.

Answer (score 0):

Considering for the [`Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) of Azure Web App sandbox, it's impossible for running some libraries like `NReco` or `ffmpeg` on Azure Function background.

And Azure Function as a serverless platform, it's not suitable for handling these heave & long-time cost job. If you have to combine Azure Function with `ffmpeg` or `NReco`, I suggest you can try to expose an API for triggering `ffmpeg` jobs on Azure VM, which will be called by HTTP request from a blob-triggered Azure Function.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be better to utilize WebJobs instead of a VM?